# Laptop wont connect to internet after sleep but will connect to network

Tags: network, wifi, sleep-wake

Ive got a MBP (spec below in screenshot) running OSX 10.10.5

Ive got an issue where every time i wake my MBP from sleep it will connect to the wifi network and my laptop will show up during a LAN scan, but will struggle to load pages it does eventually and intermittently load them, but takes for ever, even though I've got a 200mbps connection.

There are several things i can do to fix the problem, each one of them individually will fix the issue, but none are ideal :

- connect to the network through a wired connection
- restart my MBP
- restart the wifi access point
- restart the network switch

Any idea what might be causing the issue and how i can resolve it ? It doesn't happen on any of my colleagues devices only mine.

[image: screenshot of system spec]

The below 2 screenshots are from the network tab in OSX :

[image: network tab in OSX]

[image: network tab DNS tab]

For reference I've also attached a diagram of our network setup.

[image: network diagram]

Here is a screenshot of a speedtest on my machine, this is with LAN cable attached, on wifi if i get the 5ghz band im getting c. 150mbps down, on the 2.4ghz band im getting c. 40mpbs down, either way it would be plenty fast, but when i have the issue with connection as above its more like <1mbps down. Even though all other machines on my network can achieve full speed.

[image: speedtest screenshot]

Comment: Have you done an iMac Diagnostics yet?

Comment: I've had this problem to one degree or another through 3 or 4 OS upgrades and a couple of different MacBooks. Some updates to the OS make it better and some make it worse. I THINK it is a DNS issue but have yet to find a solution.

Comment: @YusaMac205 - what is iMac diagnostics i havnt come across that before ?

Comment: Knowing your specific MacBook Pro model would be helpful. Acknowledging that your OS is way outdated and trying to update it to at least 10.11 or 10.12 (if compatible) might help too. 
Try creating a new user account and see if it has the same problem. If it does, then the issue is probably hardware related. If the new account exhibits no connectivity issues then the problem is somewhere in your user profile configuration.

Comment: + on the new user, creating a new network location is worth a punt if that proves to work. Also what about manually specifying a DNS server in Sysprefs>network>advanced and/or renewing your DHCP lease (same spot).

Comment: @osxconor when you say creating a new network location do you mean like a new SSID for the wireless network ? Regarding the DNS server, this is specified at the router level (using 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) would you normally expect to see the specified on the laptop also, ive checked the laptop just now and it seems its pointing at an ISP's DNS servers (see attached updated screenshots in post), maybe thats the issue.

Comment: @sam Have you been in network settings?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of a speed test, to confirm that you actually have the 200mbps speed you think you have? We've often thought we had faster Internet speeds than we were actually getting - can you confirm that?

Comment: @DonielF see attached updated question with screenshot, this is with LAN cable attached, on wifi if i get the 5ghz band im getting c. 150mbps down, on the 2.4ghz band im getting c. 40mpbs down, either way it would be plenty fast, but when i have the issue with connection as above its more like <1mbps down. Even though all other machines on my network can achieve full speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I ask why are your DNS settings the way they are? This could definitely be a DNS issue and I don't recognize those addresses as common, just wondering.

In the Network pane of System Preferences I would want you to try and replicate this issue with a new configuration. Click the '+' symbol and select wireless adapter, try to replicate the issue now.

If the issue persists, please make a new user in System Preferences > Users & Groups with administrator access & no iCloud password. Log fully out of your user before logging into this new test account and try to replicate the issue again. Don't mess around with Network preferences -
 just let me know what you find. Also is there a reason you haven't updated beyond 10.10.5?

Comment: Im not sure why the DNS was set the way it was, i think its a ISP's DNS server for an old ISP i used to have at home. I deleted those DNS server details and its now defaulted to showing `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` which i presume its inheriting from the router as thats the default set on my router. This seems to have resolved the issue and my laptop now connects to the network much better.

Comment: Hell yeah. FYI, that's Google's public DNS servers and they're a great troubleshooting step for weird network issues like this.